# copy file to multiple folders via batch script

Tags: windows, cmd.exe

I want to copy a file (file.txt) inside all folders of a given destination. I want to create a batch file that does the job, but I'm not so skilled in Windows batch syntax.

Comment: Please clarify: do you have a single source file that you want to copy to multiple destinations? (e.g. all the subfolders inside X:/SomeFolder)?

Comment: Someting like copy myfile.txt to all folders found in d:\Destination

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the advanced version of the `for` command available from Windows NT 4 onwards:

You need something like this in a batch file:

```
for /D %%f in ("%1\*") do copy "%2" "%%f\"
```

The batch file works as follows:

- The first argument is the destination directory
- The second argument is the file to be copied

The `for` command with the `/D` switch iterates over all directories in a given path (here: `%1`) and invokes a command on each iteration. Said command is the copy operation which copies the file into every directory.

Of course, since the batch file is only a single line you can also execute it directly on the command line. Just note that the variable for `for` has only a single `%`, then.

Comment: Ok, did a pretty much complete rewrite. Undo if you see the need but a few points to remember: (1) Using `cd` in a batch file is *bad*, since it leaves the caller in a completely different directory. If you can avoid it, do so and `pushd`/`popd` are usually the way to go if you need to temporarily change the directory. (2) Always surround arguments to commands with quotes if they might contain spaces. This holds especially true for path names. (3) Never *ever* do a `for /f` over the output of `dir` if you don't desperately need it. In the default configuration the console uses raster fonts

Comment: which causes all Unicode output to be converted into the (very) legacy OEM codepage, causing unaccented characters or question marks to show up. Have fun finding *those* names then. Since `for` is capable of iterating over files and directories, both in a certain folder and recursively in a tree you never need to use `for /f` and `dir` for those cases anyway.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to read about [Xcopy](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/xcopy.mspx?mfr=true) as well.